# Why does RANDARRAY in Excel's "integer" parameter include dates that are outside of the directed min/max values?

Tags: date, random, excel-formula, array-formulas

In Excel, I am trying to create random dates based on three cell values:

| Start Date | End Date | Size | Random Dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | 1/31/2023 | 10 |  |

Where "Random Dates" is populated with:

D1: `=WORKDAY(RANDARRAY(10,1,A2,B2),1)`

Using this formula returns dates within the range, as expected.  However, when setting the Integer (I've also seen this called "whole_number") parameter of RANDARRAY to TRUE, it will sometimes select a date outside of the range (i.e., the next business date above the range).  See:

D1: `=WORKDAY(RANDARRAY(10,1,A2,B2,TRUE),1)` Can (and sometimes does) return "2/1/2023" in the spill.

I've tried to look up why this may be for dates, because it doesn't react the same way with numbers.  One thought is it has something to do with when it converts the dates selected to integers when INTEGER=TRUE, which may be because it's including time serials in the function somewhere?  I'm not sure.

NOTE: "End Date" is not a weekend date and no holidays are used.

I also tried taking WORKDAY away, which doesn't add a date outside of the max value, with either TRUE or FALSE for INTEGER.

I then added type-casted the RANDARRAY as INT:

D1: `=INT(RANDARRAY(10,1,A2,B2,TRUE))` which didn't seem to replicate the issue.

But when I added a 5th column with a WORKDAY function in each cell, it then added an additional day again:

E1: `=WORKDAY(D1,1)` filled down for each of the results.

As soon as I take the TRUE parameter out of cell D1, it goes back to even the values in column E calculating only within the range.  This strikes me as Dates passed to RANDARRAY are potentially being calculated with MAX-1 instead of just the MAX provided when INTEGER=FALSE.  Which seems like it would be strange behavior.

Comment: This is standard behaviour: 31-Jan-23 is the upper limit _only_ for the `RANDARRAY()` function, so that function can of course sometimes return that date; you have, however, nested it within the `WORKDAY()` function, with an argument of 1 to return the _next_ working day so, of course, if `RANDARRAY()` returns 31-Jan-23 (which is a perfectly valid return value), then the `WORKDAY()` function, equally validly, returns 1-Feb-23 as the _next_ working day

Comment: @SpectralInstance, thank you for the reply.  But that doesn't explain why, when still using `WORKDAY()`, but removing the TRUE flag from the integer parameter, I no longer receive any 1-Feb-23 dates.  It's still using `WORKDAY()` and still has the end_date set to 31-Jan-31.

Comment: That's simply a function of the volume of your testing - in omitting the `Integer` argument you're saying that you will accept _any_ decimal value, which means that it will take **significantly** 'longer' for an integer value to be returned.